# Como realizar una Barra de progreso 0 a 100?

Tags: android, progressbar

**Quería saber como se hace para crear esa pantalla que tienen las aplicaciones cuando abren y se cargan**, en algunas aparece un logo, en otras aparece una barra que se carga de 0 a 100. y después aparece la app.

Como se llama ese tipo de actividad y como podría hacer una. tengo un vídeo que dura 3 segundos y me gustaría ponerlo antes de mostrar la app.

Comment: no tengo el url del video, el video lo tengo como mp4, es un formato compatible? se puede cargar un video directamente de mi pc?

Comment: y utilizo un imageView?

Comment: no entiendo elena. Es necesario subir el .gif a la pregunta?

Comment: La pantalla que se muestra antes de iniciar una app se conoce como Splash Screen y en ella se puede agregar diferente contenido como lo mencionas: logos, barras de carga, imágenes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo con un **[ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)**, este es un ejemplo:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = "MainActivity ";
    Button btnDescarga;
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prueba);
        btnDescarga = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDescarga);
    }

    public void descargar(View view){
        progress=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Descargando algo....");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
       // progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setProgress(0);
        progress.show();

        final int totalProgressTime = 100;
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int jumpTime = 0;

                while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime) {
                    try {
                        jumpTime += 5;
                        progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
                        sleep(200);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

layout_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Ejemplo Progress bar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDescarga"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Descargar"
        android:onClick="descargar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

tendrías algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]