# Como puedo añadir una progress bar circle en mi proyecto con firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, firebase

Quiero añadir a mi proyecto cuando inicie sesion el usuario que aparezca un circulo de carga mientras se inicia sesion con el siguiente metodo de firebase

```
 private void iniciarSesion(String email, String password){
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                Log.i("Sesion","Exito en el inicio de sesion");
                abrirSiguienteVentana();
            }
            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                Log.i("sesion", "Fallo en el inicio de sesion");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Primera Forma**
Bueno una de las formas es usar un `ProgressDialog`.

Declaramos una variable global

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

Ahora en tu método `onCreate` deberas inicializarlo

```
progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
```

A partir de ahi puedes llamar el progresbar en tu metodo de logueo

```
private void iniciarSesion(String email, String password){
//agregas un mensaje en el ProgressDialog
progressDialog.setMessage("Iniciado sesión");
//muestras el ProgressDialog
progressDialog.show();      
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
             progressDialog.dismiss();
             Log.i("Sesion","Exito en el inicio de sesion");
             abrirSiguienteVentana();
         }
         if(!task.isSuccessful()){
            //cierra el progressbar
            progressDialog.dismiss();
             Log.i("sesion", "Fallo en el inicio de sesion");
         }
     }
 });
}
```

**Edited**

**Segunda Forma**

Ahora bien si lo que buscas es una animacion con tus propios estilos, podemos crear un nuestro propio `ProgressBar` y usando la clase `ObjectAnimator`.
Te muestro un pequeñp ejemplo de como hacerlo

1. Deberemos crear nuestro `Drawable`, para eso vamos en nuestro proyecto en la carpeta `Drawable`, clic derecho y **New->File** al cual llamaremos **circular.xml**.

Quedará de la siguiente forma.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:useLevel="true">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

2.- En nuestro layout deberemos de agregar el `ProgressBar`, te dejo el siguiente ejemplo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="osorio.org.progressbarcircle.MainActivity">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/circularProgress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="158dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="48"
    android:progress="1"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Autenticando!"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

3.- Inicializamos y corremos nuestra

```
package osorio.org.progressbarcircle;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressBar miprogress;
private ObjectAnimator anim;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //instanciamos el progrogressbar
    miprogress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circularProgress);
    //instanciamos el animador
    //Construye y devuelve un ObjectAnimator que anima.
    anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(miprogress, "progress", 0, 100);
    mostrarProgress();
}

private void mostrarProgress(){
    //agregamos el tiempo de la animacion a mostrar
    anim.setDuration(15000);
    anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    //iniciamos el progressbar
    anim.start();
}
}
```

**El resultado sería el siguiente**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA**

Para llamarlo seria de la forma en que te explique en la primera parte

```
private void iniciarSesion(String email, String password){
//llamas al método
mostrarProgress();   
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
             //para cancelar la barra usarias
             anim.cancel();
             Log.i("Sesion","Exito en el inicio de sesion");
             abrirSiguienteVentana();
         }
         if(!task.isSuccessful()){
            //para cancelar usar
            anim.cancel();
             Log.i("sesion", "Fallo en el inicio de sesion");
         }
     }
 });
}
```

**Adjunto el proyecto del progressbar**
[ProgressBarCircle](https://mega.nz/#!dlBFwApb!yL47_vODm4p8T21BAOIk64JugmdhSd3qpDnvahrUs2U)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió !

Answer (score 2):

La forma más sencilla es simplemente definir un Progressbar el cual sería visible/invisible al iniciar o terminar tu proceso, los 4 tipos de estilos posibles son:

El estilo `android:progressBarStyleHorizontal` que es una tipica barra de progreso horizontal:

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

[image]

Los otros son barras de progreso circular en 3 diferentes tamaños:

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
```

[image]

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
```

[image]

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
```

[image]

Defines tu ProgressBar:

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </ProgressBar>
```

Un enlace que te servira de utilidad:

[¿Cómo mostrar un ProgressBar mientras se obtiene una respuesta del servidor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39648/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-un-progressbar-mientras-se-obtiene-una-respuesta-del-servidor/39665#39665)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Una barra de progreso circular puede indicar únicamente que se esta realizando un proceso, en cambio una progressbar horizontal podría indicar el progreso de tu proceso:

[Como realizar una Barra de progreso 0 a 100?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7354/como-realizar-una-barra-de-progreso-0-a-100/7358#7358)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]